# OutOfMemory Error in ArrayList. Android

Tags: android, json, arraylist, out-of-memory, http-get

I am working on http get request on android.

I receive a huge amount of json data from server, a string is unable to handle or store that data and getting OutOfMemory Exception.

Then I tried to save it in arrayList which can store a maximum of Integer.Maximum value.
 but it is getting OutOfMemory exception while storing at ~8970 location.

Here is my link which has json data.

http://ec2-50-19-105-251.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ad/Upload/getitemlist10122013035042.txt

here is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> newarr = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

        URL url = new URL(urlFilePath);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        // connect
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Stream used for reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        // create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        int check;
        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            String decoded = new String(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            newarr.add(decoded);    // OutOfMemory Exception.   
        }

        fileOutput.close();
        buffer = null;
        inputStream.close();
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return path;
    } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION:: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Try using `StringBuilder` instead of `String` and check if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried just now, but it did not worked. getting the same error.

Comment: Try commenting out `newarr.add(decoded);` and see if it still crashes.

Comment: can u able to trace after which item id its getting out of memory error ?

Comment: Why you need data in string here, since this is json data. You need to extract json-data. Is there any special case in your scenario? If all you need is data, then you can refer: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Comment: @ Apoorv : yes I have hidden  newarr.add(decoded);

Comment: @ FunLove : I am not sure but approx it is some where near ~25897

Comment: @ GauravGupta : I dont mind whether my json data should store in a string or not, but it should receive complete data with no data loos and no exception. From your link I did not find where data receiving from service call.. Please suggest.

Comment: see my answer below..try and revert back to me

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the stream directly instead of storing it as a String.  Look at the Gson Stream Reader as an example:

```
public List<Message> readJsonStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        Message message = gson.fromJson(reader, Message.class);
        messages.add(message);
    }
    reader.endArray();
    reader.close();
    return messages;
}
```

You can think of the List here as the parsed result.  You could also use the list from whatever `ListAdapter` you are using if you want to display it.